Can't Log in in Django users
I am writing a site with a custom user model. I want to access the site via telegram. Everything works, but the authentication itself - the login function does nothing(
I don't understand what's wrong, I've been trying different ways for 3 days now, but nothing works. I will be glad to any advice. And here is my code
#users/views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.models import AuthCode
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from django.contrib.auth import login, get_user_model
from users.backend import TelegramAuthBackend

User = get_user_model()


class GenerateTelegramCodeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        expiry_time = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)
        new_code = AuthCode.objects.create(
            session_id=request.session.session_key, expiry_time=expiry_time
        )
        return JsonResponse({"code": str(new_code.code)})


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class TelegramAuthView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        telegram_id = request.POST.get("telegram_id")
        code = request.POST.get("code")
        auth_backend = TelegramAuthBackend()
        try:
            auth_code = AuthCode.objects.get(code=code, expiry_time__gt=timezone.now())
            if auth_code:
                auth_code.is_used = True

                user = auth_backend.authenticate(request, telegram_id=telegram_id)
                if user is None:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(telegram_id=telegram_id)
                    user = auth_backend.authenticate(request, telegram_id=telegram_id)

                if user:
                    auth_code.telegram_id = telegram_id
                    auth_code.save()
                    return JsonResponse({"status": "ok", "message": "Ok!"}, status=200)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse(
                        {"status": "error", "message": "Authentication failed"},
                        status=403,
                    )
            else:
                return JsonResponse(
                    {"status": "error", "message": "Invalid or expired code"},
                    status=400,
                )
        except AuthCode.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"status": "error", "message": "Code not found"}, status=404
            )


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class AuthenticateView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_backend = TelegramAuthBackend()
        auth_code = AuthCode.objects.filter(
            session_id=request.session.session_key, expiry_time__gt=timezone.now()
        ).first()
        print(auth_code)
        if auth_code.telegram_id is not None:
            user = auth_backend.authenticate(request, telegram_id=auth_code.telegram_id)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user, backend='users.backend.TelegramAuthBackend')
                return JsonResponse({"isLoggedIn": True, "message": "Ok."})
        else:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"isLoggedIn": False, "message": "User is not logged in."}
            )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "users/authenticate.html")

#users/backend.py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class TelegramAuthBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, telegram_id=None):
        logger.debug(f"Trying to authenticate user with telegram_id={telegram_id}")
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(telegram_id=telegram_id, is_active=True)
            logger.debug("User found and is active")
            return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            logger.debug("User not found")
            return None

#users/models.py
from django.db import models
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class AuthCode(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    telegram_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.code} - Expires at {self.expiry_time}"


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, telegram_id, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not telegram_id:
            raise ValueError(_('The Telegram ID must be set'))
        user = self.model(telegram_id=telegram_id, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, telegram_id, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(telegram_id, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    telegram_id = models.CharField(_('Telegram ID'), unique=True, max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('Staff status'), default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'telegram_id'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.'),
        related_name="customuser_set",
        related_query_name="customuser",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name="customuser_set",
        related_query_name="customuser",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.telegram_id

#authenticate.html (script)
<script>
    function checkLoginStatus() {
        fetch('/users/auth/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.isLoggedIn) {
                console.log(data.message);
                clearInterval(loginStatusInterval);
                window.location.href = "/";
            } else {
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
    
    let loginStatusInterval = setInterval(checkLoginStatus, 1000);    
</script>

#base.html (script)
<script>
    function openLoginModal() {
        document.getElementById('loginModal').style.display = 'block';
    }
    
    function getTelegramCode() {
        fetch('/users/telegram_auth/generate_code/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                window.open(`https://t.me/bot_name?start=${data.code}`, '_blank');
                document.getElementById('loginModal').style.display = 'none';
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "/users/auth/";
                }, 1000);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                alert('We had an error.');
            });
    }
    
    
    function authenticateUser(telegram_id, code) {
        fetch('/users/telegram_auth/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ telegram_id: telegram_id, code: code })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.status === 'success') {
                alert('Success');
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
</script>

I read the official documentation and tried to understand the source code. But I didn't find anything suspicious there

What do you mean your auth view does nothing? -- Are you saying the view isn't called or you aren't getting the output you expect? What is the output of the variable here: auth_code = AuthCode.objects.filter(             session_id=request.session.session_key, expiry_time__gt=timezone.now()         ).first()?

I mean, the login function doesn't do anything. It doesn't actually authorize the user. auth_code correctly retrieves data from the database. Here is an example of its value:
1de01d57-53b8-49b2-a289-edfa3850eda2 - Expires at 2024-04-29 21:49:59.036215+00:00
Also if we go further, the user variable and request.user are equal to the desired value from the database. Everything works except login
I also tweaked my code a bit, I added a custom backend

Here is my console:
[00:48:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 24646
[00:48:19] "GET /users/telegram_auth/generate_code/ HTTP/1.1" 200 48
[00:48:21] "GET /users/auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5021
[00:48:22] "POST /users/telegram_auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 34
1de01d57-53b8-49b2-a289-edfa3850eda2 - Expires at 2024-04-29 21:49:59.036215+00:00
[00:48:23] "POST /users/auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 38
1de01d57-53b8-49b2-a289-edfa3850eda2 - Expires at 2024-04-29 21:49:59.036215+00:00
[00:48:23] "POST /users/auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 38
[00:48:24,426] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 62021)
[00:48:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 24646
